# Whose "jealousy" is Karenin referring to?

Tags: meaning

Alexandrovich Karenin confronts his wife Anna, who is moving
closer to Vronsky, a cavalry officer:

> Alexandrovich Karenin: You and Count Vronsky attracted attention tonight.
>
> Anna: You don't like it when I don't talk to people, and you don't like it
> when I do.
>
> Alexandrovich Karenin: I didn't notice anything myself, but I saw everyone else noticed.
> I consider **jealousy** to be insulting to you and degrading to me. I have no right to
> inquire into your feelings.

Whose "jealousy" is Karenin referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karenin is referring to his own (supposed lack of) jealousy. He himself is not so much concerned with Anna's friendship with Vronsky, but with the fact that everybody else notices.

So he isn't complaining about the relationship, but in effect asking her to be more discreet.